# backbone model getting created multiple times with rapid clicks

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

When the user clicks this camera icon the get a snapshot of the page in a modal. If they click repeatedly it will make multiple snapshots before the modal has loaded and essentially blocked the camera icon.

Is there a way that I can say if a snapshot modal has just been created do not create another one?

```
events: {

    'click .snapshot-camera'      : 'clickCamera'
}

clickCamera: (event) ->
    event.preventDefault()

    @snapshot = new ******.Models.Snapshot({ user_id: ******.State.get('signInUser').id })
```

Comment: Underscore's throttle() function is your friend here.  It will prevent multiple function calls for the same event within a specified number of milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can use underscore's debounce method which prevents double submissions.

```
// prevent double-click
$('button.my-button').on('click', _.debounce(function() {
  console.log('clicked');

  /* .. code to handle form submition .. */
}, 500, true);
```

Have a look into the below article

http://jules.boussekeyt.org/2012/backbonejs-tips-tricks.html